Flutter app some devices are excluded by rule in Google Play Console
I am using flutter to release my android app and using this command to upload a build :
flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --release --split-debug-info=/Users/foxtom/StudioProjects/project_name/build --build-name=1.0.0 --build-number=1
And i see this device for example that is excluded in my Play Console Device catalog :

I would like to understand why it is excluded ?
Here is my manifest file :
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:label="My App Name"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-ejfqifjq"
            />

        <property
            android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG"
            android:resource="@xml/gma_ad_services_config"
            tools:replace="android:resource" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->

            <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="false" />

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.mywebsite.com" android:pathPrefix="/any" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility?hl=en and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>


and my build.gradle file :
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace "com.myapp_android"
    compileSdk 35
    ndkVersion "27.1.12297006"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.android"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 35
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.4.0"
    implementation 'com.giphy.sdk:ui:2.3.15'
}

I hope that if i can find an answer for this device i will find for other devices.
Note : Google Play Support told me to

ask a question since we can't help with technical issues.

EDIT : I have raised a github issue in Flutter repo to see if they have more insights.
The weirdest thing is that i can "Exclude" the devices that are apparently already excluded, but it's like they are considered not excluded... And if i click on "Manage exclusion rules", there are no rules at all obviously...


Do you use Play Integrity API ?
In my app i had set it up to "Device integrity checks (recommended)" but when I have lowered it to "Basic integrity checks" it didn't exclude anything.
The funny thing is that Google writes : "Devices excluded based on Play Integrity verdicts aren't shown in the tables below"
But this is simply a wrong statement. Give it a try despite the Google sentence.

It is working thank you !!

In the "Device catalog", when viewing a device, at the top where it says "Overview" there's a "Show more" link. In my Play Console, it lists the actual reasons why the device is unsupported.
See this screenshot with the "Show more" on the right:


Thanks for your answer, however it's not the same because the device is not unsupported, it is excluded by rule and it's written "Supported in all tracks with active release" where you it's written "Not Supported in some tracks".
If i click on the Show more, it display the Tracks and the Status is always "Supported". But what is this "Rule" that is excluding the device ?

In my openion issue of your Flutter app being excluded on some devices in the Google Play Console could stem from several factors related to your Android manifest and Gradle configuration.

You have set minSdkVersion to 23. Ensure that the devices you're targeting support this version or higher. If some devices are running an older version of Android, they will be excluded.

The permission RECORD_AUDIO is declared but not used in the manifest. If your app requires specific permissions that are not properly handled, it may cause issues during submission.

Your targetSdkVersion is set to 35, which is relatively new. Ensure that all libraries and functionalities used in your app are compatible with this SDK version.

The configuration for ad services (AD_SERVICES_CONFIG) might not be correctly set up, which could lead to issues on certain devices.


your refiend code :
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapp.android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <!-- Ensure internet permission if using ads -->

<application
    android:label="My App Name"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-ejfqifjq" />

    <property
        android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG"
        android:resource="@xml/gma_ad_services_config"
        tools:replace="android:resource" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="false" />

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.mywebsite.com" android:pathPrefix="/any" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent>
</queries>


Thanks for your reply, but the problem didn't come from my config or Flutter itself, it was really Play Integrity checks that were excluding these devices...
Note : The "not-opted-in" devices were also included when i lower the play integrity checks despite they were not "excluded-by-rule"
